# Is it possible to call a self calling function method some where?

Tags: javascript

I have a self calling function.

```
var controller = new (function () {
    this.func = function {    
    };
});
```

This get's executed on the first page, i want to access the function in my another page. how can i access that method alone...

Comment: store in js file as common function and link in both the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var controller = new (function _controller() {
    this.func = function {    
    };
});

var otherController = new _controller();
```

Be wary of [named function expressions and IE](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript code needs to be included in every separate page that needs to use it. Assuming by "that method" you mean the "func()" function defined by the "controller" constructor, you'd have to instantiate an object and then call through it:

```
var myController = new controller();
myController.func();
```